# Does creating snapshot make cluster slow?

Tags: elasticsearch

I use ElasticSearch 5.6.

When running snapshot, I run 
   http://localhost:9200/_cluster/health
but did not get response for more than 10 sec.
I can also see when snapshot runs, machines have a lot of costs at disk/network IO.

Such a delay does not happen if I do not run snapshot.

I check _cluster/health with timeout to ensure that creating snapshot does not slow-down queries.
Is it the correct way to check this?
In practice will creating snapshots make queries slow down?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is increased disk activity as indices are read however excerpt from elastic documentation states:

*The index snapshot process is incremental. In the process of making the index snapshot Elasticsearch analyses the list of the index files that are already stored in the repository and copies only files that were created or changed since the last snapshot. That allows multiple snapshots to be preserved in the repository in a compact form. Snapshotting process is executed in non-blocking fashion. **All indexing and searching operation can continue to be executed against the index that is being snapshotted**.*

Apart from _cluster/health check taking more than 10 secs do you see any impact to data indexing/ searching etc ?

How frequently are you running the snapshots ? Is it a full cluster snapshot ? Where is the snapshot repository - filesystem / s3 / Azure/ Google cloud ?

Comment: I did not see indexing/searching slow actually. This is a snapshot after a full one, so should be incremental, and the repository is s3.